# HttpClient result from a WebAPI Request.CreateResponse (StatusCode, Message)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI method that looks like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody] LoginType form)
    {
        if (LoginFails(form.Email, form.Password)
             return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                            "Sorry your login failed");

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

I have an Client that looks like this:

```
        var sample = new LoginType()
        {
            login = "test",
            Password = "password"
        };

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("www.example.com);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
               new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/security/login", sample).Result;
```

**QUESTION 1:** Where in the result variable, I can read the message "Sorry your login failed" ??
**QUESTION 2:** When returning a CreateErrorResponse, does it make sense to return HttpStatusCode.OK ??

Comment: Take a read of this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html In short, invoking `.Result` on async tasks is a really bad idea.

Comment: You ask this question many times, You can put in response whatever you want as the .Content, As far of the message context (OK, BadRequest, etc..) it depends on what your client expects / your architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: From `Response.Content`. If content type is application/json, you can do:

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Q2: I would return `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` if the login failed.

Comment: Maybe I'm assuming that a StatusCode 300, 400 or 500 makes the browser to AUTOMATICALLY redirect to an error page. I guess it's a bad assumption on my part !!!

Comment: It's up to your client to handle status codes the way that you want, but it's still the right practice to return a status code that corresponds to what happened. If login failed then it's not "OK".